# how to send array of params using volley in android

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I am developing an application which send lot of data to server.Now i want to send an array of params to a php page using volley.But i am not able to send it.

**Code for adding params as Array.**

```
String[] arr =new String[7];
    for(int i=1;i<=7;i++)
    {
        arr[i]="questionId_"+i+"_"+"ans_"+i;

    }
    HashMap<String ,String[]> params=new HashMap<String, String[]>(7);
    params.put("params", arr);
```

**Code for making request to server**

```
RequestQueue que=Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

     final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(HealthMyHistory.this);
     dialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
     dialog.setMessage("Sending Data");
     dialog.setCancelable(false);
     dialog.show();


    CustomJobjectRequest jsObjRequest = new CustomJobjectRequest(Method.POST, url, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                {
                    dialog.dismiss();



                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError response) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to Send Data!"+" "+response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    que.add(jsObjRequest);

}



Problem is in CustomJobjectRequest there is no constructor available of type in which Hashmap accepts string & array as argument.How to do it ?
```

**Code or CustomJsonObjectRequest**

```
 package com.example.healthcoach.data;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener;
import com.android.volley.Response.Listener;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser;


public class CustomJobjectRequest extends Request<JSONObject>{

    private Listener<JSONObject> listener;
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public CustomJobjectRequest(String url, Map<String, String> params,
              Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
          super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);
          this.listener = reponseListener;
          this.params = params;
    }

    public CustomJobjectRequest(int method, String url, Map<String, String> params,
              Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
          super(method, url, errorListener);
          this.listener = reponseListener;
          this.params = params;
      }

  public CustomJobjectRequest(int post, String url,
            HashMap<String, String[]> params2, Listener<JSONObject> listener2,
            ErrorListener errorListener) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

@Override
  protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
    return params;
  };

  @Override
  protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
      listener.onResponse(response);
  }

  @Override
  protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
       try {
              String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                      HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
              return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                      HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
          } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
              return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
          } catch (JSONException je) {
              return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
          }
  }

}
```

Comment: `CustomJobjectRequest` class your own class ? please show code

Comment: @prosper K 
Check my code please

Comment: see my edit answer which is probably what you want

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
HashMap<String ,String> params=new HashMap<String, String>(7);
for(int i=1;i<=7;i++)
{
    params.put("params_"+i, arr[i]);
}
```

in `CustomJobjectRequest` class because currently you are using `String` type as value in Map in `CustomJobjectRequest` class but sending `String[]` type when create object of `CustomJobjectRequest` class.

**Edit:**

To send all values in single parameter to server use `JSONObject`.Create a json object using all key-value as:

```
 JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
 for(int i=1;i<=7;i++)
    {
        arr[i]="questionId_"+i+"_"+"ans_"+i;
        jsonObject.put("params_"+i,arr[i]);
    }
HashMap<String ,String> params=new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("params",jsonObject.toString());
```

TO send all values on server side get `params` and convert to JSON object and iterate to get all values

Comment: Why can't i create a constructor which accept HashMap<String,String[]> in CustomJsonObjectRequest class?

Comment: @TechGuy: `getParams()` or other methods which you ar eoverrding from `Request<JSONObject>` class is use `Map<String ,String>` instead of `HashMap<String ,String[]>` so you should use `Hash<String ,String>`

Comment: Ok is this only way to send array of params?

Comment: @prosper K  sir i want get an array of params on server end as in php

Comment: @TechGuy: pass  Array as parameter is not possible but you can send all values in single parameter using JSONObject. create a JSONObject  with all values then send it to server as `HashMap<String ,String> params=new HashMap<String, String>();params.add("params", jsonobject.toString());` Now on php side convert received string from `params` to JSONObject to get all values

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206258/how-to-add-list-into-params-of-volley-android please help me

Comment: Thanks for your idea friend. Its working for me . I have used like this Code :  JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray();
            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
            {
                jsonArray.put(list.get(i));
                Log.d("ClassRoomAtt", "jsonObje--->" + jsonArray.toString());

            }

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
    Map<String, String> postParam = new HashMap<>();
    int i=0;
    for(String object: friendIds){
        postParam.put("friendIds["+(i++)+"]", object);
        // you first send both data with same param name as friendnr[] ....  now send with params friendnr[0],friendnr[1] ..and so on
    }
```

this work for me, hope it work to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use google json Library to make json array.

```
 compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

And this code is to put json array in the body of the request

```
private void sendTokenToServer(final String jsonArrayString) {
        String tag_string_req = "string_req";
        String url = Const.SEND_TOKEN_TO_SERVER;


        final StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                hideProgressDialog();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hideProgressDialog();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
                header.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                return header;
            }


            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                try {
                    return jsonArrayString.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

        };
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1

> Make json param

```
 Map<String, String> jsonParams = new HashMap<>();
```

Step 2

> Make set or Arraylist  why set or arraylist because no need to put fixed lenth

```
  private Set<String>  arr;
  for(int i=1;i<=7;i++)
    {
        arr[i]="questionId_"+i+"_"+"ans_"+i;
        arr.add("params_"+i,arr[i]);
    }
```

Step 3 pass set object as a string

```
 if (arr!= null) {
       jsonParams.put("param", arr.toString());
                  }
```