# Volley pass array as parameters

Tags: android, android-volley

i'm ussing volley to send post requests to my php backend but i'm unable to pass an array as parameters... or add multiple parameters with the same name which only add the last param in the for loop to the params

this code works but only return the last number as parameter and not both numbers:

```
  protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
            numbers.add("+431111111111");
            numbers.add("+432222222222");

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            for(String object: numbers){
                params.put("friendnr[]", object);
            }
            return params;
        }
```

i just want to pass an array, list of "friendnr" to my php backend..

thx

Comment: see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49979639/7328984

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your for each loop is buggy...

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
        numbers.add("+431111111111");
        numbers.add("+432222222222");

        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

        int i=0;
        for(String object: numbers){
            params.put("friendnr["+(i++)+"]", object);
            // you first send both data with same param name as friendnr[] ....  now send with params friendnr[0],friendnr[1] ..and so on 
        }
        return params;
    }
```

Comment: May I ask how I would be able to retrieve the result in PHP?

Comment: @user3484582 check this [send arrylist and handle in php and then get the response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38175956/3288890)