# send arraylist as parameter in volley request

Tags: android, android-volley, jsonexception

I'm trying to send arraylist containing numbers as parameter in volley request and then parse it and display the values (in string) in toast. But I'm getting null in response. I would like to know where is the problem.

```css
json response:

{
  "got_members": [
    "1",
    "2"
  ]
}
```

```html
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment{

    Button checkme;
    private static final String ADDMEM = "http://www.example.com/api/event/addmembers/", KEY_ADDMEM = "adding_members";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.searchfragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        checkme = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.checkme);
        checkme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                checkarraylist();

            }
        });
    }

    private void checkarraylist(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, ADDMEM,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        if(response != null){
                            try {
                                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                        }else {

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            try {

                                JSONArray itemArray = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("got_members");
                                for (int i = 0; i < itemArray.length(); i++) {
                                    String value = itemArray.getString(i);
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Result:" + value + "\n", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // JSON error
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
                strings.add("10");
                strings.add("20");
                strings.add("30");
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                int i=0;
                for(String object: strings){
                    params.put("adding_members["+(i++)+"]", object);
                    System.out.println(object);
                }

           /*    String array[]=strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]);

                for(String k: array)
                {

                    params.put("adding_members", k);
                    System.out.println(k);
                } */



                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;  charset=utf-8");
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }




}
```

Answer (score 3):

First in your Object in ArrayList: create JSONObjectmethod name as getJSONObject, like this

```
public class EstimateObject {
String id, name, qty, price, total;
public EstimateObject(String id, String name, String qty, String price, String total, int position)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.qty = qty;
    this.price = price;
    this.total =total;
    this.position = position;
}
 public JSONObject getJSONObject() {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    try {
        obj.put("Id", id);
        obj.put("Name", name);
        obj.put("Qty",qty);
        obj.put("Price", price);
        obj.put("Total", total);
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Aftrer Here is how I converted it,in my activity

```
    JSONObject JSONestimate = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray myarray = new JSONArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {

        try {
            JSONestimate.put("data:" + String.valueOf(i + 1), items.get(i).getJSONObject());
            myarray.put(items.get(i).getJSONObject());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Log.d("JSONobject: ", JSONestimate.toString());
    Log.d("JSONArray : ", myarray.toString());
```

Here i converted both type JSONObject and JSONArray.

After in

```
map.put("jsonarray",myarray.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the JSONObject first . Then get the JSONArray . like this way ->

```
try {
    JSONArray array = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("got_members");
    for (int i = 0; i < itemArray.length(); i++) {
        String value=itemArray.getString(i);
        //Log.e("json", i+"="+value);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Result:" + value+"\n", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following code alongwith your overriding getParams() function

```
@Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
//Parameters added here
}

@Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;  charset=utf-8");
            return params;
        }
```

Also you need to change this line

```
JSONArray itemArray = new JSONArray("got_members");
```

to

```
JSONArray itemArray = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("got_members");
```

Comment: I changed my way of sending parameter by converting the arraylist to string. But now I'm only getting value "20" and not "10".

Comment: `for(String k: array)
                {
                    params.put("adding_members", k);
                }`   
you are putting same key for multiple value. If key is same in HashMap it will replace previous data.

Comment: Its the same as my code. I'm still getting the last value only in response. @nitinkumarp

Comment: I am saying that your previous code was correct. The code I posted in comment is your and I am saying to revert.

Comment: But with previous code I was not getting anything in response and I think it was due to `"adding_members["+(i++)+"]"` in params.put(). @nitinkumarp

Comment: I don't think it would cause any problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109686/discussion-between-somnath-pal-and-nitinkumarp).

Answer (score 1):

This may be the late response but as per response example this could help a bit

```
try {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            String someString = String.valueOf(i);
            jsonArray.put(someString);
        }
        object.put("got_members", jsonArray);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: its not working for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206258/how-to-add-list-into-params-of-volley-android?noredirect=1#comment89393472_51206258 please help me i want to add list into params of volley android

Answer (score 0):

First get the response in JsonObject and then retreive the JsonArray or change the string request to JsonArray request

```
 try {
      JsonObject object=new JsonObject(response)

                            JSONArray itemArray = new JSONArray("got_members");
                            for (int i = 0; i < itemArray.length(); i++) {
                                String value=itemArray.getString(i);
                                //Log.e("json", i+"="+value);
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Result:" + value+"\n", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }



                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // JSON error
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
```

or simply use `JSONArray array = new JSONObject (response).getJSONArray("got_members");`

Comment: Your code is not correct . 
`JSONArray itemArray = new JSONArray("got_members");` This line should be `object.getJSONArray("got_members")`

Comment: Both answers are same but after changing it in my code I'm not getting any Toast. I should be getting the "String value" in toast

Comment: Where you want to add that toast. You want multiple toast or single toast. ??. Thanks  Zainul Islam for ur suhhestion

Comment: I checked the "response" in Toast, I'm getting `{"got_members":[]}`. This means, the arraylist in parameter is not being sent properly.

Comment: Yes. You are right. If the response is empty then your toast will not show.

Comment: If the response is {
  "got_members": [
    "1",
    "2"
  ]
} this, then two times toast will display

Comment: So, is there any better way to send arraylist<string> as parameter in volley post request? As its clear that the fault is in parameter @Ameer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109663/discussion-between-ameer-and-somnath-pal).

Comment: It should be `JSONArray array = new JSONObject (response).getJSONArray("got_members");`

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of sending whole arraylist,if you are sending contact

```
@Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

            ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);

            while (phones.moveToNext())
            {
                String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
               numbers.add("\n"+name+"\n"+phoneNumber+"\n");

            }
            phones.close();

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            int i=0;
            for(String object: numbers){
                params.put("a"+(i++), object);
             if(i==10)
               break;
            }
            return params;
```

> now handle this on server side

```
$response=array();$response["res"]=array(); foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
if(strpos($k, 'a') === 0) {
    $res=array();
    $ab=$k = $v;
    $res["name"]=$ab;array_push($response["res"],$res);}}echo json_encode($response);
```

> now after response

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {

                JSONObject stdent = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray students = stdent.getJSONArray("res");
                for (int i = 0; i < students.length(); i++) {
                    String ab=students.getString(i);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  ab, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
```