# pass array data as parameter volley

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-volley

i have array look like this

```
arrayname[{"code" : "abc","code2":"cba",}]
```

i want send it as paramaters,put it in getParam() function with volley to my server

the problem look similiar to this

[Volley pass array as parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32881832/volley-pass-array-as-parameters)

any help how to do it?

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know how to pass single data from the volley library to server , because i didn't worked on the volley library

Comment: I have an answer for this I had to do this also.... please wait...

Comment: something look this  protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
                numbers.add(kode);
                numbers.add("1");

                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("req","req");
                params.put("msisdn",msisdn);
                params.put ("tujuan",nomor);

Comment: @BooberBunz thank you..i'll wait

Comment: Hmmmm I think maybe I thought your question was more complicated than it is.  Sorry.

Comment: see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49979639/7328984

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you have to make JsonArrayRequest. In Volley there is JsonArrayRequest class use that one for JsonArray request.

This is the method available in JsonArrayRequest class.

```
public JsonArrayRequest(int method, String url, JSONArray jsonRequest, 
            Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, (jsonRequest == null) ? null : jsonRequest.toString(), listener,
                errorListener);
    }
```

May be this will help you:

```
JSONArray jArrayInput=new JSONArray();
JSONObject jObjectInput=new JSONObject(); 
jObjectInput.put("code", abc);
jObjectInput.put("code2", cba);
jArrayInput.put(jObjectInput);

JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Method.POST, /*Your base url*/, jArrayInput , new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //Here success response
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   //Here error response
                }
            });
            MyVolley.getRequestQueue().add(request);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method in an app I made that does what you're trying to do. (I think?)

My problem was that I had multiple post parameters that I wanted to send, but one of them was an array.

For example:

```
http://www.yourDB.com/getData.php?param1=blah&param2=blah&param3=[ [array] ].
```

So... to make sure that the PHP page understands that I'm sending an array, I add data to the array as follows (notice the ' [] ' following the param).

```
postParams.add(new String[]{"param3[]", itemName});
```

So... the server sees this:

```
http://www.yourDB.com/getData.php?param1=blah&param2=blah&param3[]=item1&param3[]=item2&param3[]=item3...
```

The key to understand is this part:

```
"@Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {"
```

The trick is that you send an ArrayList of String arrays into the method and override the getBody() part like this:

```
private void Url_2_Adapter(String url, final ArrayList<String[]> postParams) {

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    // do something with response

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // Log.i(TAG, "WE HAD ERROR " + error.toString());

            try {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Server says: Error code " + error.networkResponse.statusCode + "\nIf this continues, please report it! Thanks.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            catch (Exception e){

            }

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {

            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            boolean first = true;

            for (String[] entry : postParams)
            {
                if (first) {
                    first = false;
                } else {
                    result.append("&");
                }
                try {
                    result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry[0], "UTF-8"));
                    result.append("=");
                    result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry[1], "UTF-8"));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // this basically will never happen :)
                }
            }
            return result.toString().getBytes();
        }
    };
    Z_VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(stringRequest);

}
```

Comment: Sorry...l this answer makes more sense IF your array is like this:    paramname["item1","item2,"item3","item4","item5" ... ]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't worked on the Volley Library , I used AsyncHttpClient : The logic you can apply here like this:

```
JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray();
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(); 
jsonObject.put("code", abc);
jsonObject.put("code2", cba);
jsonArray.put(jsonObject);// this you need to pass using volley library
```