# How to insert an ArrayList to mysql using Volley

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley

I want to insert an `ArrayList` that contain some String and some integer into `MySQL` using Volley in android. This is how I want to send my array in android. 
I dont know if  this is right or not.

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("Authorization", user.getApikey());
    return params;
}

@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
   for(int i=0; i<wordlist.size();i++){
       params.put("word_id["+i+"]",String.valueOf(wordlist.get(i).getWord_id()));
       params.put("word["+i+"]",wordlist.get(i).getWord());
       params.put("translation["+i+"]",wordlist.get(i).getTranslation());
       params.put("english["+i+"]",wordlist.get(i).getEnglish());

   }
   return params;
}
```

The problem is I have no idea how to get an `ArrayList` in `PHP` with POST data and how to use it to insert my data to `MySQL`. 
I would be really grateful if some body tell me how to handle `PHP` part with example and even if I am doing right in android part or not.

Comment: Post what u hv tried and specifically where u r stuck

Comment: as i said i could not  find any thing in php part to try so i did not try any thing . any way ty for your negative

Comment: _i could not find any thing in php part_. You need to learn to use google!

Comment: thank for your advice :|

Comment: See this for PHP, [Android login and registration with php mysql and sqlite](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/), and [volley-pass-array-as-parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32881832/volley-pass-array-as-parameters) for volley.

Comment: tanx bro @KNeerajLal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("Authorization", user.getApikey());
return params;
}

@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("list",wordlist);
return params;
}
```

Then in your PHP side

```
 $list = $_POST["list"];
 for($i=0;$i<count($list);$i++){
//do something
}
```

EDITED

```
 public void sendSomeToSql(){
    final JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject ok = new JSONObject();
    for (int i = 0; i < wordlist.size(); i++) {
        ok.accumulate("list", wordlist.get(i));
    }
    array.put(ok);
    try {
        data.accumulate("list", array);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "url", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Authorization", user.getApikey());
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("list", String.valueOf(data));
            return params;
        }
    };
}
```

Try this one, hope it works. Earlier i was just trying to address how the php side accept the data from android.

Comment: ty dear it gave me the key  r :| sry if i cant give a postitive to you cuse im below 15 reputation

Comment: i checked it :s you cant put an array as has param

Comment: I updated my answer and i guess i have to use JSONArray to be sent to the PHP side

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but your job is simpler than you think. Your android java code is almost right, you just need a simple php code.

Android (My own code):

```
 @Override
     protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
         Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
          for(int i=0;i<contactslistm.size();i++) {
         params.put("id", ID);
         params.put("list["+i+"]", contactslistm.get(i));

       }
          return params;
   }
```

PHP:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){


var_dump($_POST['list']);
$id=$_POST['id'];

foreach ($_POST['list'] as $value) {


$insert="INSERT INTO `testdata` (`id`,`userid`,`object`) VALUES (NULL,'$id','$value')";
   $result=mysqli_query($con,$insert);
    
}
```