# How can I pass a simple Integer[] to Volley?

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I am using Volley successfully to pass and receive JSONArrays and JSONObjects, but the API I'm using requires that I pass in a simple Integer array [1,2,3] in a PUT request. Any ideas?

Here is a snippet from the API documentation.

> **PUT api/commuters/{id}/favorites**
>
> Update the list of favorite commuters associated with the specified
>   commuter.
>
> **REQUEST**
>   **Body Parameters:** Collection of integer Request Formats
>   **application/json, text/json, text/html Sample:** [   1,   2 ]
>
> **RESPONSE**
>   none

Comment: Have a look to this stacoverflow [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32882196/4770978).

Comment: That is a valid JSON array, so you could stick with your existing logic. Or, use `TextUtils.join()` to handle the comma-delimiting, then wrap the result in square brackets. Or, iterate over your integers yourself and build up a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: When overriding the getParams method it requires a Map<String,String>. How do I pass in a JSONArray?  I feel like this should be a simple solution so I must be missing something.

Comment: Convert JsonArray to JsonObject. and then convert jsonobject to String.

Comment: we can parse json object in api side

Comment: trying some of these recommendation . . . thanks. I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: Tried to covert JSONArray to JSONObject and passed in:
`
    {
       "273078": 273078,
       "330248": 330248,
       "322971": 322971
    }
`
But this returned a status 500.

Comment: @suresh Once I convert my jsonarray > jsonobject > string how should I handle that in the getParams method?  It requires a return of Map<String,String>.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to sending text to a Volley Request is overriding the getBoddy method to print out your text/json.

Here is my method for putting the integer array:

```
public static void putFavorites(final JSONArray data, final MyApp.StringCallback callback) {

    String url = APP_API + "commuters/" +
            MyApp.getPrefs().getInt("commuterId", 0) + "/favorites";
    StringRequest stringRequst = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String result) {
                    try {
                        callback.onSuccess(result);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    callback.onError(volleyError);
                }
            }) {


        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "text/json";
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            Log.d(TAG, (data.toString()).getBytes().toString());
            return (data.toString()).getBytes();
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> headers = VolleySingleton.getInstance(GACommuter.getAppContext()).getVolleyHeader("text/json");
            return headers;
        }
    };

    stringRequst.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            20000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
    ));

    addToRequestQueue(stringRequst);
}
```