# send volley post request with parameters

Tags: android, android-volley, androidhttpclient

I try to send post request with parameters.I have `getParams` method and i inserted my parameters in `HashMap`. But `Hashmap` override elements  each other.This is my Volley's `getParams` method

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("train[]", "860");
    params.put("class[]", "32");
    params.put("rank[]", "2");
    params.put("adult[]", "1");
    params.put("child[]", "0");

    params.put("train[]", "0");
    params.put("class[]", "0");
    params.put("rank[]", "0");
    params.put("adult[]", "1");
    params.put("child[]", "0");

    return params;
    }
```

I debugged it and params length is 5. i want to params length should be 10.
How i can solve my problem?

Comment: you are currently not adding the params just overwrite it. you need to create an array and add it to params.please try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32881832/volley-pass-array-as-parameters.

Comment: keys are unique in a HashMap, if you try to put a value with an existing key, the previous value will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayList instead of HashMap

Comment: Volley' getParams method does not support Arraylis @Kiran Koravi

Comment: @Baggio have you tried the link in the above comment?