# Android sending array in a url as parameter

Tags: java, php, android

I am trying to send data to an API that will accept one of it's parameters as an array. 
In PHP it is very simple to put an array as a parameter using http_build_query() function like this:

```
http_build_query (
    array (
           'text' => 'Hello',
           'info' => array('apple', 'banana')
     )
)
```

It would yield:

```
text=Hello&info%5B0%5D=apple&info%5B1%5D=banana
```

That I can later use as parameters for my URL

Is there a way to do this concept in andriod? I'm using Volley to make the requests to the server as I will expect JSON returns.

Comment: This may be duplicate. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32881832/volley-pass-array-as-parameters

Comment: This may be helpful as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272248/how-to-send-array-of-params-using-volley-in-android/49979639#49979639

Comment: @danwebb sorry tried those already, didn't work for me :/