# Array params in Volley StringRequest

Tags: php, android, arrays, android-volley

I have some trouble with sending a StringRequest. One of my params must be an array

Here is the request:

```
public void sendToWebService(final String login, final String mdp, final Reprise rep){
    String url = MyApplication.getUrlWs();
    final RequestQueue request = RequestQueueSingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            rep.setStatus(1);
            RepriseDAO db = new RepriseDAO(context);
            db.addVehicule(rep);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("login", login);
            params.put("password", mdp);


            ...


            JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray();
            for (Equipement equ : rep.getEquipements()) {
                jarray.put(equ.getId());
            }
            String data= jarray.toString();
            params.put("carOptions", data);

            params = checkParams(params); //this put an empty string if a param is null
            return params;
        }
    };

    request.add(sr);
}
```

This is the php code of the webservice. I only show the interesting part:

```
foreach($_POST['carOptions'] as $v)
{
    $query_options='INSERT INTO cars_options_car (carId, optionId) VALUES (' . (int)$lastId . ',' . (int)$v . ')';
    $request_options=mysql_request($query_options); 
}
```

As you can see, the webservice expect to receive an array in the "carOptions" param. After a little research, I've tried to make a JSONArray and convert it into a String. The request is well received by the webservice but it seems like the array is not well converted.

Should I use an other kind of request ? I've tried a JSONRequest but it seems like my webservice doesn't accept JSONRequest.

Comment: What problem do you face?

Comment: the webservice expect to get an array but it receive a string. I've made some local test and managed to turn the string into an array using the php fuction explode() but the webservice provider refuse to change his script

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272248/how-to-send-array-of-params-using-volley-in-android)