# How to pass an array to POST API?

Tags: java, android, post

In my Android application, I need to send an array as body (payload information) to a POST url.

In body, there are two params:

```
1. "env" : "dev"  
2. "dNumber" : tn("+1232323"); // here I need to send an array.
```

Edited question: I need to send phone as an array like ["123131","4545545"]

I pass the array as created a JSON array and convert to string and passed.

```
private String tn(String tn) {
    String json = "";
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        jsonArray.put(0, tn);
        json = jsonArray.toString();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return json;
}
```

and full code is:

```
    try {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        url = new URL(makeCallUrl);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", String.format("%s %s", "Basic", secretKey));
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();
        // Setup the body of the url
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        json.put("env", "dev");
        json.put("destNumbers", tn("+123123"));

        // Write the body on the wire
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream()));
        writer.write(json.toString());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IOException:" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If I try this, I got 400, Bad request exception.
Please help me to pass an array to POST api

Comment: what is tn ---json.put("destNumbers", tn("+123123"));?

Comment: A 400 could mean anything.  Check with the server log and see why it failed (assuming your server).  If its not your server, check with the docs and make sure you sent the data in the format it actually expects.

Comment: Also, from what you posted, I see nothing that I would think takes an array.

Comment: @MilanPansuriya, creating a json array format

Comment: @M.A.Murali can you add your tn method with your question

Comment: @MilanPansuriya, I edited my question. there is tn() method

Comment: You may check this lead;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272248/how-to-send-array-of-params-using-volley-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem using JSONArray and pass the array.

```
        // creating json array
        JSONArray numberArray = new JSONArray();
        numberArray.put(0, tn);

        // send the array with payload
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("env", "DEV");
        json.put("destNumbers", numberArray);
```

Now I get array as following:
destNumbers = ["3434343","3434334]

Comment: what is a JSONArray, where do I find this ?

Answer (score 0):

Update your tn() method. Instead of returning String it should return JSONArray.

```
private JSONArray tn(String tn) {
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
   try {
       jsonArray.put(0, tn);
   } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return jsonArray ;
}
```

Although if still the 400 Bad request error occur than confirm and verify the request payload with your json.