# android volley how to send array?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

So heres my stuff basic getParams post method in volley but I don't know how to send array to backend can someone help?

```
@Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
//looping throught recyclerview
            for (int i = 0; i < CustomCreateGroupAdapter.dataModelArrayList.size(); i++){
//getting selected items
            if(CustomCreateGroupAdapter.dataModelArrayList.get(i).getSelected()) {
                    try {
//putting all user ids who you selected into jsonObject
                        jsonObject.put("params", CustomCreateGroupAdapter.dataModelArrayList.get(i).getOthersid());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("params",jsonObject.toString());


    return params;
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like you're trying to send an array.  Maybe use JSONArray?

Comment: see [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28272442/4854891 "")! hope it will help you. Happy Coding... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add all those values to a [JSONArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray) and then add this JSONArray to your JSONObject. You could also add all objects to a simple array and then get the corresponding JSONArray by calling `new JSONArray(your_array);`

Answer (score 0):

Add the objects of your payload to a [JSONArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray), then use `JSONArray.toString()` to pass the payload to a [JsonRequest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/jb-mr1-dev-plus-aosp/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonRequest.java) as the `requestBody`.