# how to send array as parameter in android

Tags: android, arrays, parameters

```
service_category_type :
[
      {parent_service_id: "5c78df0f9ed89a3ea251ad", child_service_id : "5c78df409ed89a3ea251ad"},
      {parent_service_id: "5c78dd1763f38236efdf35", child_service_id : "5c78dfb79ed89a3ea251ad"},
      {parent_service_id: "5c78dd0563f38236efdf35", child_service_id : "5c78df9c9ed89a3ea251ad"},
]
```

how to send this array as a parameter. I am using this link:
[how to send array of params using volley in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272248/how-to-send-array-of-params-using-volley-in-android)
   but not able to do. I need help to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Using this method:

```
public static Object mapOrListToJson(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof Map) {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        Map map = (Map) object;
        for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
            Object o = mapOrListToJson(map.get(key));
            if( o == null )
                return null;
            try {
                json.put(key.toString(), o);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return json;
    }
    else if (object instanceof Iterable) {
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
        for (Object value : ((Iterable)object)) {
            Object o = mapOrListToJson(value);
            if( o == null )
                return null;
            json.put(o);
        }
        return json;
    }
    else {
        return object;
    }
}
```

you can transform your array into a `JSONArray`.

Then, you can transform it to a String representation using `toString()` method:

```
String jsonStr = myJsonArray.toString();
```

Finally, you can send your String to your server.