# How to pass multiple information array and a image array to server?

Tags: android, android-volley

I have an array which is contain image quantity for image and another is image size array which is contain image size, also an image array. I'm trying to send them to server but i failed every time. I'm trying many example but nothing was worked for me. Is there any other way to do this ? Please give me some hints or link.

[how to send array of params using volley in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272248/how-to-send-array-of-params-using-volley-in-android)

```
public void uploadMultipleImage(String url, final List<SelectedImageModel> selectedImageModels)
{
    VolleyMultipartRequest multipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            String resultResponse = new String(response.data);
            responseListener.onResultSuccess(resultResponse);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
            String result = new String(networkResponse.data);
            responseListener.onResultSuccess(result);
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>(selectedImageModels.size());

            for(int i=0; i<selectedImageModels.size(); i++)
                params.put("size["+i+"]",selectedImageModels.get(i).getPhotoSize());

            for(int i=0; i<selectedImageModels.size(); i++)
                params.put("quantity["+i+"]",selectedImageModels.get(i).getPhotoQuantity());

            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders()  {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();

            headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer "+requiredInfo.getAccessToken());
            headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
            headers.put("Content-Type", "x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
            Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>(selectedImageModels.size());

            for(int i=0; i<selectedImageModels.size(); i++)
                params.put("image["+i+"]",new DataPart("imageName",UserProfile.getFileDataFromDrawable(selectedImageModels.get(i).getPhoto())));


            return params;
        }
    };

    requestQueue.add(multipartRequest);
}
```

Every time i'm getting com.android.volley.server error 500 this error

Answer (score 0):

Make a method for send array of params.

```
      private String makeJsonObjectParams() {


//In mediaData,I am sending image to AWS and I will get the download link and I
```

// am storing the downloadurl in downloadurl arrayslist.

```
 JSONArray mediaData = new JSONArray();
    try {
        if(img1 != 1) {
            JSONObject temp = new JSONObject();
            temp.put("file", download_url.get(0));
            temp.put("type", "signature");

            mediaData.put(temp);
        }

        if(img2 != 1){

                JSONObject temp1 = new JSONObject();
                temp1.put("file", download_url.get(1));
                temp1.put("type", "id proof");

                mediaData.put(temp1);

        }



    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //for sending normal details like text
    JSONObject updateDetails = new JSONObject();
    try {


        updateDetails.put("status", 2);
        updateDetails.put("userId", sharedPreferences.getString("user_ID",""));
        updateDetails.put("deviceToken", splash_screen.android_id);




    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject jsonVerificationDetails = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonVerificationDetails.put("type", verificatin_type);
        jsonVerificationDetails.put("durationOfStay", durationOfStay.getText().toString());

        jsonVerificationDetails.put("media", mediaData);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonBody.put("verificationDetails", jsonVerificationDetails);
        jsonBody.put("updateDetails", updateDetails);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final String mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString();

    return mRequestBody;
```

}

}

Through the below code send the code to server.

```
 void submitData(){

        try {
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
            final String mRequestBody = makeJsonObjectParams();

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, completedTaskUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                       //do whatever you want
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                    }


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                }


                @Override
                public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                    try {
                        return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                        VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", mRequestBody, "utf-8");
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                    String responseString = "";
                    if (response != null) {

                        responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);

                    }
//                    return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                    return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
                }
            };
            requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        } catch (Exception e) {//JSONException e
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```